# Is there a way to export my webpage from Bubble to a different server?

Tags: html, web

Is there a way to export the "Code" from bubble.io to build my own server?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is not possible in the moment.

Best regards
Jakob

Comment: Be sure to update this answer in case support does get added please.